# Relative paths using javascript in different browsers

Tags: javascript, relative-path

I am using JavaScript to open a particular page relative to the current directory that I am in. The directory structure is:

```
a/b/c/firstpage.html
```

If, I am currently in firstpage.html and I want to navigate to b/secondpage.html:

in **IE9/10**, I use the following code:

```
../secondpage.html
```

While in **Chrome**, I have to use the following code:

```
./secondpage.html
```

because if I use 2 dots in Chrome it will go to a/secondpage.html

Can you please tell me how can I solve this to be compatible across all broswers?

Comment: chrome does not behave as you say it does. `./` stands for the current working directory, so clicking on a link to `./secondpage.html` when you are on `a/b/c/firstpage.html` is the same as clicking a link to `a/b/c/secondpage.html` .  `../` works as you described: moving up one level in the dir tree. This works the same in chrome as in IE and any other browser.  You must not actually be doing what you think you are doing.. provide more details and code for what you are actually trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Use split and go two levels up in the current url, then concatenate your second url:

```
var loc = window.location.href.split('/').slice(0,-2).join('/');
var url = loc + '/secondpage.html';
```